# sha256 signature with OpenSSL returns unreadable string

Tags: php, sha256, php-openssl

I'm trying OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA256 on php7. Everything is looking fine without any error, but a result looks terrible. How can I fix that?

```
openssl_sign($plaintext, $signature, $privateKeyId, OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA256);
echo $signature;
```

result:

[image]

Comment: bin2hex($signature)

Comment: @clover It's working fine. Thx